# How to write to remote linux directory

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

How to expose a directory in remote ubuntu server so that I can read & write to that directory from remote machines.

Actually, I have a web application and I need to write to the AWS EC2 instance's directory and create directories using java program running in another server.

Note: I do not want to run a java program in AWS instance just for writing files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use sftp from Java: https://www.example-code.com/java/sftp.asp or https://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server

Comment: I am looking for some FREE solution. :)

Comment: I see other results for JSch: https://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server

Comment: Thank you Alex. That helped. I've implemented the same. thanks a lot.